# How to develop interactive animated plots in Clojure?

Tags: user-interface, plot, clojure

I have an idea to develop application which will receive data online and update plot every second. Also there should be some interactive functionality, i.e. showing information about data point while mouse is hovering on it.

I want to develop this application in Clojure but I have no experience in GUI. I have tried to use `incanter` but I couldn't show anything except plot on the window (I also need textboxes etc). I am currently playing with `quil` but I couldn't find the way to place plots from `incanter` there.

What is the best way to develop this application and which libs should I use?

Comment: Does it have to run in JVM?  This is the sort of thing I'd be tempted to do in a browser with clojurescript; there are tons of excellent JavaScript charting libraries from d3 on up to leverage, plus reagent and other react wrappers to make cheaply responsive.

Comment: I have zero experience with ClojureScript. I need to have an access to file io, if that is possible I can try something

Comment: That might make it a bit hassleful :-). Maybe try some of the suggestions here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160168/interactve-and-dynamic-plots-charts-in-clojure

Comment: I have already checked that option but it seems that I would need to develop too many things by myself. There are bunch of amazing plotting libraries in JS, is it possible to use them in standalone app? Something like ClojureScript with those libs and Electron?